# Uploading a large file in chunks with C# HTTP REST API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have code a backend C# .NET Core web api to receive byte[] and store on server side. Later I plan to append each such file and construct the file.

The client is WPF and I am trying to chunk a file and upload it.

I have some code like the following?

```
FileStream FS = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        int FSBytes = (int)FS.Length;
        byte[] B = new byte[megabyte];
        int Pos;

        List<byte[]> Data = new List<byte[]>();

        for (Pos = 0; Pos < (FSBytes - megabyte); Pos += megabyte)
        {
            FS.Read(B, 0, megabyte);
            Data.Add(B);
        }

        B = new byte[FSBytes - Pos];
        FS.Read(B, 0, FSBytes - Pos);

        Data.Add(B);
        FS.Close(); FS.Dispose();
```

What i would like to do is read 4 chunks, send them to the API, after each one is successfully posted then send the next 4 and so on.

I was thinking of creating a list of tasks and sending each item as the task. However the issue I have is how to stop the file reader and resume when the queue is empty.

Any ideas will help.

Comment: Check this article: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1034347/Upload-large-files-to-MVC-WebAPI-using-partitionin

Comment: Thanks, this is good code but I am looking for multi-threaded approach.